# Java send and receive data from python program in another computer

Tags: java, python, networking

Recently I tried to send data with java to a python program. I learned about `socket`. It was very good, fast, and useful, but the only problem was, the socket cannot send and receive data without the same network. There is any way to send data to my python program without being in the same WiFi network?

Thank's for any help

Comment: Research into web servers perhaps (Apache is quite easy to set up), either find a free domain name or buy one, then you should be able to access that across computers perhaps

Comment: It will be possible if I will connect to the socket with public IP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of two solutions creating a webserver or attempting to directly connect to the ip or hostname of the second computer.

The simple way (may need some changing I have not tested this):
Get the second computer's IP address if you do not know it visit here - https://www.whatismyip.com/ on either device or if you are on linux run `hostname -I` (if you get 127.0.0.1 change the capitalisation of your i) or for windows in cmd run `ipconfig` you can also get the device hostname for windows run `hostname` (probably the same for linux and mac) next you can run this code for python

```
import socket
s = socket.socket()
# Define the Ip and port you wish to connect too
s.connect(('<IP ADDRESS GOES HERE>', <PORT NUMBER (MUST BE OPEN)>))
```

This will create a connection to the second computer and allow you to communicate with it.

This next one is far more of an undertaking and may be a touch more floored read the whole then before trying.

The harder way creating a webserver (this will be much better for having more than two computers connected) I will show you how to run apache, the most popular and it's free which is nice) (this could be done on a third device to avoid strain I can recommend something like a raspberry pi that you can leave around running your server - how to set it up here (https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7207/how-do-i-make-my-raspberry-pi-web-server-public - for making it public and here - https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/web-server/apache.md - for installing it)

For windows now - first make sure there is NOTHING running on port 80 (where it will be hosted) install this a version of apache from here - https://www.apachehaus.com/cgi-bin/download.plx. From prior use you can use 2.4.46 with SSL for stability with the following instructions also make sure you have a visual C++ installation (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads-2647da03-1eea-4433-9aff-95f26a218cc0).

Now go to the apache file and extract the contents into a file then open command prompt as admin (left click > run as admin)

Go to the file you extracted it to with cd  then into Apache24\bin and run `start httpd.exe` allow it access to public and private networks. To test go to http://localhost you should see something like the following

[image: base apache installation (2.4)]

If it works good :) Now stop it in the same directory using

```
apachectl -k stop
```

Next install the apache services themselves so you can  run programs on it.

```
httpd.exe -k install -n "Apache HTTP Server"
```

Once done restart your server with `httpd -k restart` and go backto the local host page.

You now (Should) have a working web server on your computer you now have a few more steps so I'll leave some links for them all and my suggestions.

If this does not work it may be the fire wall see here - https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-apache-on-a-windows-server/

To let it go public see here - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sCGIwLL0CSw

To make a callable database you could use flask if you want something simple in python - https://programminghistorian.org/en/lessons/creating-apis-with-python-and-flask, running it on the webserver here - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Pcy44-wtio.

I can highly recommend the first options and don't really recommend running apache on a windows machine putting it on a raspberry pi is a much better idea with flask_restul.

Hope this is helpful please ask if you need any more help.

Comment: If you use Flask here are some libraries for using sending requests to it - (Python - https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html) (Java - https://square.github.io/retrofit/) Should be most things covered.